# How to sign a string with HMAC-SHA1 algorithm

Tags: algorithm

I want to sign a string with HMAC-SHA1 algorithm.As the instruction I should use this two string:

```
encodedPutPolicy = "eyJzY29wZSI6Im15LWJ1Y2tldDpzdW5mbG93ZXIuanBnIiwiZGVhZGxpbmUiOjE0NTE0OTEyMDAsInJldHVybkJvZHkiOiJ7XCJuYW1lXCI6JChmbmFtZSksXCJzaXplXCI6JChmc2l6ZSksXCJ3XCI6JChpbWFnZUluZm8ud2lkdGgpLFwiaFwiOiQoaW1hZ2VJbmZvLmhlaWdodCksXCJoYXNoXCI6JChldGFnKX0ifQ==";
SecretKey ="MY_SECRET_KEY";
```

To get such signed string

```
signedString = "c10e287f2b1e7f547b20a9ebce2aada26ab20ef2"
```

I don't know this is which programming language in that instructional web-page:

> sign = hmac_sha1(encodedPutPolicy, SecretKey )

From [this relevant post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/94891/hmac-implementation-in-pure-mathematica?s=1|1.8233),I get a such function for my case:

```
hash[string_String, method_String : "SHA"] := 
  FromCharacterCode@
   Interpreter["HexInteger"]@
    StringPartition[IntegerString[Hash[string, method], 16], 2];

HMAC[key_String, message_String, method_String: "SHA", 
   blockSize_Integer: 64] := 
  Module[{char54, char92, key2, ipad, opad}, {char54, char92} = 
    FromCharacterCode /@ {54, 92};
   key2 = 
    Switch[StringLength@key, blockSize, key, l_ /; l > blockSize, 
     hash[key, method], _, 
     StringPadRight[key, blockSize, FromCharacterCode@0]];
   ipad = 
    FromCharacterCode[
     BitXor @@ 
      Map[ToCharacterCode, {StringRepeat[char54, blockSize], key2}]];
   opad = 
    FromCharacterCode[
     BitXor @@ 
      Map[ToCharacterCode, {StringRepeat[char92, blockSize], key2}]];
   hash@StringJoin[opad, hash@StringJoin[ipad, message]]];
```

But it will give messy code like following:

```
HMAC[SecretKey, encodedPutPolicy]
```

> "Á.0e(+.1eT{ ©ëÎ*­¢j.b2.0eò"

---

And as [the pseudocode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash-based_message_authentication_code#Implementation) provided by WIKI,

[image]

I give following try:

```
hmac[key_, message_] := 
 Module[{keyLen = StringLength[key], dkey, opad, ipad, blocksize = 64,
    method = "SHA"}, 
  dkey = If[keyLen > blocksize, IntegerString[Hash[key, method], 16], 
    StringPadRight[key, blocksize]]; {opad, ipad} = 
   FromCharacterCode[
      BitXor[ToCharacterCode@
        StringRepeat[FromCharacterCode[FromDigits[#, 16]], 
         blocksize], ToCharacterCode@dkey]] & /@ {"5c", "36"}; 
  IntegerString[Hash[StringJoin[opad, ipad, message], method], 16]]
```

But as you see,the following rusult different with my expected and [the exmaple of Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash-based_message_authentication_code#Examples).

```
hmac[SecretKey, encodedPutPolicy]
hmac["key", "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog"]
hmac["", ""]
```

> "4e44cbeea3fcfea721bcbdd7f40853e62fc34a7c"
>
> "a13add58c73437e1c876ffd0e6f1acc80f143f7e"
>
> "629d1b940615d4072d48027a898cee7942a889b0"

Anybody can give some help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default padding string of `StringPadRight` is a space, but what we need here is `0x00`.

And the last line of the pseudocode is `return hash(o_key_pad ∥ hash(i_key_pad ∥ message))`. There are two `hash`s.

```
hmac[key_, message_] := 
 Module[{keyLen = StringLength[key], dkey, opad, ipad, blocksize = 64,
    method = "SHA"}, 
  dkey = If[keyLen > blocksize, IntegerString[Hash[key, method], 16], 
    StringPadRight[key, blocksize, FromCharacterCode[0]]]; {opad, 
    ipad} = FromCharacterCode[
      BitXor[ToCharacterCode@
        StringRepeat[FromCharacterCode[FromDigits[#, 16]], blocksize],
        ToCharacterCode@dkey]] & /@ {"5c", "36"};
  IntegerString[
   Hash[StringJoin[opad, 
     ExportString[
      IntegerDigits[Hash[StringJoin[ipad, message], method], 256], 
      "Binary"]], method], 16]]
```